# Circular Reference Error with Spring Integration and JPA updating outbound gateway

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-data-jpa

I have been trying to figure out the issue with circular reference in the following spring integration flow.

I am using Spring Boot Auto Configuration for entityManagerFactory and transactionManager beans.

Here is the integration context with two jpa:updating-outbound-gateway that reads the message from two different channels and send the response to a one common channel.

```
<int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter
        id="jmsListener" connection-factory="connectionFactory"
        channel="queueChannel" destination="queueName"
        error-channel="errorChannel"/>

<int:chain input-channel="queueChannel" output-channel="dbChannel">
    ....
    // more stuff
    ....
</int:chain>

<int-jpa:updating-outbound-gateway id="updatingGateway1" request-channel="dbChannel" entity-manager-factory="entityManagerFactory" entity-class="com.example.MyMessage1" persist-mode="PERSIST" reply-channel="reportChannel" reply-timeout="5000">
    <int-jpa:transactional transaction-manager="transactionManager" propagation="REQUIRED"/>
</int-jpa:updating-outbound-gateway> 

<int:channel id="errorChannel"/>

<int-jpa:updating-outbound-gateway id="updatingGateway2" request-channel="errorChannel" entity-manager-factory="entityManagerFactory" entity-class="com.example.MyMessage2" persist-mode="PERSIST" reply-channel="reportChannel" reply-timeout="5000">
    <int-jpa:transactional transaction-manager="transactionManager" propagation="REQUIRED"/>
</int-jpa:updating-outbound-gateway>

<int:channel id="reportChannel"/>
<int:logging-channel-adapter channel="reportChannel" expression="payload"/>
```

I am getting the following error when running the application.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceInitializerPostProcessor': 
Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not 
autowire field: private org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory 

org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializerPostProcessor.beanFactory; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.integration.jpa.outbound.JpaOutboundGatewayFactoryBean#0': 
Cannot resolve reference to bean 'updatingGateway2.jpaExecutor' 
while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'updatingGateway2.jpaExecutor': 
Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' 
while setting constructor argument; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration': 
Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not 
autowire field: private javax.sql.DataSource 
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.dataSource; 
nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 
'org.springframework.integration.jpa.outbound.JpaOutboundGatewayFactoryBean#1': 
Cannot resolve reference to bean 'updatingGateway1.jpaExecutor' while 
setting constructor argument; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'updatingGateway1.jpaExecutor': 
Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting  
constructor argument; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory': Requested bean 
is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
```

However if I remove one of the

```
<int-jpa:updating-outbound-gateway ..>
```

flow, the application runs fine. Any comments or suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: You only have to remove 1 gateway? Or both? Can you post a small app (e.g. on github) that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: I just need to remove one. Removing any one of the gateway and the apps run fine.

Comment: Does it matter which one?

Comment: I wonder what is `errorMessageUpdatingGateway`... We don't see it's definition in your config.

Comment: I have been able to reproduce it locally. Strange situation: we fail when we have more than one `entity-manager-factory="entityManagerFactory"` usage. Investigating...

Comment: Ok thanks, yes the errorMessageUpdatingGateway is a mistake, it is supposed to be updatingGateway2.

Comment: See my answer, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I think we have exactly this issue: https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-3857: CTOR injection causes the deps to be instantiated too early for the `FactoryBean`.

Unfortunately we have just released SI-4.2.4, so the fix for `JpaOutboundGatewayFactoryBean` will be somewhere later.

Meanwhile can you try to use this as workaround?

```
<bean id="jpaOperations" class="org.springframework.integration.jpa.core.DefaultJpaOperations">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>

<int-jpa:updating-outbound-gateway jpa-operations="jpaOperations" />
```

Instead of `entity-manager-factory="entityManagerFactory"`.

The JIRA ticket on the matter: https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-3916.

Comment: yes the jpaOperations bean with XML config worked fine, but the Java Config threw the same error.

Comment: Java Config? Something new here? Share that, please!

Comment: Using @Bean
    public JpaOperations jpaOperations(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory){
        DefaultJpaOperations jpaOperations = new DefaultJpaOperations();
        jpaOperations.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
        return jpaOperations;
    } didn't worked, but the xml in your answer worked.

Comment: Right, because exactly `JpaOutboundGatewayFactoryBean` uses CTOR injection and that must be fixed. Since you use some XML already, I assume you can live with one more simple `<bean>` there until our fix :-)

Comment: :) yes, I will go with the xml. I am using xml for integration flow only as it is easier to visualize with the diagram, otherwise I prefer the Java Config for my bean configuration. thanks again for the workaround.